# Test mail using gmail smtp using swiftmailer?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I m trying to send an email from a PHP script running on localhost. I am using the gmail smtp server and swiftmailer. Following is the code:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('myusername')->setPassword('mypassword');
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message->setSubject('Email from testing');
    $message->setFrom(array(
        $cleanEmail => $cleanName
    ));
    $message->setTo(array('navjot.dcrust@gmail.com'));
    $message->setBody($cleanMsg);

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    if($result > 0) {
        return $response->withRedirect($request->getUri()->getBasePath());
    } else {
        return $response->withRedirect($request->getUri()->getBasePath().'/contact');
    }
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
Details

Type: Swift_TransportException
Code: 535
Message: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k11sm8212449wmb.18 - gsmtp "
File:   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
Line: 383
```

Comment: I know you aren't necessarily using Laravel, but Laravel is using swiftmailer in the question I indicated as a possible duplicate, and it seems likely that yours is failing for the same reason indicated there.

Comment: Yes I got your point.Thanks a lot